# How can I set the paper size with SWIFT / iOS, so my thermal printer airprints more than 140mm

Tags: ios, swift, thermal-printer, airprint

I have made an app, and the app needs to print a receipt. I have a star TSP650 II thermal printer that supports AirPrint.
I can print and that works fine. The use of previous selected printer also works fine.

However, it cuts automatically after 140mm, and sometime my receipts can get 2 or 3 timers longer.

How can I programmatically set the paper length ?

```
    func SelecteDefaultPrinter(){
        let printerPicker = UIPrinterPickerController(initiallySelectedPrinter: nil)
        printerPicker.present(from: CGRect(x: 0, y: -100, width: 600, height: 500), in: self.view, animated: true) { (printerPicker, userDidSelect, error) in
            if userDidSelect {
                //Here get the selected UIPrinter
                self.defaultPrinter = printerPicker.selectedPrinter!
                let js="storeprinter('\(printerPicker.selectedPrinter!.displayName)','\(printerPicker.selectedPrinter!.url)');"
                self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
                self.printerURL = printerPicker.selectedPrinter!.url
                self.user!.printerurl = printerPicker.selectedPrinter!.url.absoluteString
                print(self.user!)
                //   self.printText()
            }
        }
    }

    func printText() {
        let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
        printInfo.jobName = "print Job"
        printController.printInfo = printInfo
        let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)
        formatter.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)

        printController.printFormatter = formatter

        if(printerURL  ==  URL(string: "http://notset.local")) {
            print("no printer selected");
            printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            let currentPrinter = UIPrinter(url: printerURL!)

            printController.print(to: currentPrinter, completionHandler: {(controller, success, error) -> Void in
                if success {
                    debugPrint("Printing Completed.")
                } else {
                    debugPrint("Printing Failed.")
                }
            })
        }  
    }
```

I am fairly new to the whole iOS / SWIFT, so please help.

Comment: Isn't that a setting in the printer?

Comment: As far as I can see, I cannot choose different paper sizes because apple only has a set of standard presented.

Comment: According to the [Airprint manual](https://www.starmicronics.com/Support/Mannualfolder/AirPrint_Users_Manual.pdf) the print sized is fixed at 140mm. You will probably need to use a Bluetooth or WiFi socket connection to the printer rather than using AirPrint.

Comment: Gosh Dang it! I was hoping for a " You can change paper length so easily" :)

Comment: So, Star Intelligent, the manufacture of the printer does support a variety of different connections. They have their webPRNT and I think that it will do the trick for me. I does require a lot of reprogramming, but hey, that's life :) 
https://www.starmicronics.com/pages/WebPRNT

Still if any finds the golden solution, please let me know :)

Comment: I bought a STAR SM-L200 but didn't manage to connect it to my app.. was hoping there would be an easier AirPrint way to do this...

Comment: It will probably be a better result in the end. You will be able to void the AirPrint dialog

Comment: The AirPrint dialogue is already avoided in my code once the printer is selected.

Using the WebPRNT solution provided is a fairly easy solution to use. You cannot make the receipt as pretty. It also gives some issues when it comes to selecting the printer, but it works.